# Would a DAC reduce hissing I hear from headphones?

Tags: audio, sound-card

Even when nothing is playing I hear a lot of hissing and noise in my headphones. They are connected to the front audio jack on a desktop PC. I read that electrical interference is particularly bad at the front panel as it doesn't have much electrical shielding. Would connecting the headphones to a DAC that connects to a USB port solve this problem? What is the difference between cheap DACs ($50) and expensive ones ($200)?

Comment: A snap-on ferrite bead for $1 might solve it.

Comment: @spiff do you have more info on this? What kind of bead, does it go on the power input or audio output? Do they really help in audio circuits?

Comment: @Spiff where would I buy this? Do you have any references?

Comment: They're also called "ferrite chokes" or "ferrite cores". They're too cheap to sell individually online, so you might have to buy an assorted-sizes 20-pack for like US$12 on Amazon. If you have a brick-and-mortar electronics supply store like Radio Shack around, you can probably buy them individually from a bin. Get the snap-on/clip-on kind that are split in half so you can easily snap the two halves together around your audio cable. They help attenuate EMI that might be traveling up your cable. I can't guarantee this will solve your problem, but it's a super cheap thing to try.